# How do I send a JavaScript variable to another page when using JQuery UI

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hey guys So I have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".NotesAccessor").click(function () {
       var notes_name = $(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().html();
      run();
    });
});
```

This get a name for when someone clicks on the attribute and from there goes to this function that opens and starts the dialog:

```
function run(){
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';
    showUrlInDialog(url);
}

function showUrlInDialog(url)
    {
      var tag = $("#dialog-container");
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data).dialog
          ({
              width: '100%',
                modal: true
          }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }


function update()
    {
        $.ajax({
        url: '/PCG/termsofservice/accepted.php',
        success: function() {
            $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );

            }
          });

    }

function closeNotes()
    {
        $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
    }
```

So give the variable notes_name over to a variable in PHP in the file that is opened up in the Jquery UI?  Or do I have to send it over?  I am not to certain on what to do.

David

Comment: Do you have control over the markup and the way this is structured? If so, you're over complicating things.

Comment: There must be a better alternative to: `$(this).parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().html();`

Comment: Am I?  Lee there is but lol.

Comment: @LeeTaylor [$.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `$.ajax()` function has a method for passing data:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/PCG/termsofservice/accepted.php',
  data: { /* data object goes here */ },
  success: function() {
      $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
  },
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: But what about because its being opened up in JQuery UI can't I just access it on the other page because of when it calls?

Comment: Javascript is a client side language. It has no way of passing variables between different pages. The scope of each page is unique.

Comment: I have a question how would I recieve it on the other end?

Comment: Using PHP? `$_GET["variable"]`. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: But how would you do that when you are sending it over in post format in the .ajax?  In the data string.

Comment: after passing my data through and running it I get `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` in chrome - my data value is` data:
  {
   nameNotes: notes_name,
  }`